# "Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server" error after adding users to PAM section

Tags: ssh, pam

When I add users in the PAM section of sshd_config:

```
UsePAM yes
Match User employee_1
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I cannot restart the SSH service and get the message below (Why? pls help):

```
root@ip-xxxxxxx:/etc/ssh# systemctl status ssh


● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-04-23 18:19:00 UTC; 19s ago
  Process: 895 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2183 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 895 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: ssh.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 23 18:19:00 ip-publicip systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version? I don't see anything wrong with what you did (unless you accidentally corrupted other parts of the config file). You can try executing sshd in debug mode `/usr/bin/sshd -d` to see if that flushes out the error.

Comment: Hi many thanks for replying, not really a linux guy just started almost a month ago forced by work necessity.

What i have is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

When i issue the /usr/bin/sshd -d 
result is:  -bash: /usr/bin/sshd: No such file or directory

Comment: Apologies - that should have been `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` (or just plain `sshd -d`, since `/usr/sbin` should be in root's path)

Comment: Here's the result:

root@ip-public:/etc/ssh# systemctl restart ssh
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

root@ip-public:/etc/ssh# /usr/sbin/sshd -d
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 94: Directive 'PrintMotd' is not allowed within a Match block

Answer (score 0):

There are really no "sections" in an `sshd_config` file.

In the default file, `UsePAM` happens to be the last line of the file, and so that's why you will typically see `Match` blocks immediately following it. The rules for `Match` blocks are described in `man sshd_config`:

> ```
>      Match   Introduces a conditional block.  If all of the criteria on the
>              Match line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines
>              override those set in the global section of the config file,
>              until either another Match line or the end of the file.  If a
>              keyword appears in multiple Match blocks that are satisfied, only
>              the first instance of the keyword is applied.
> ```

As we discovered by running the server in debug mode with `sshd -d`, you have at least one additional line **after** `UsePAM` in your `sshd_config` file, and by placing your Match block ahead of this line, `sshd` is trying to apply it inside the block - which is not allowed (refer to the `Match` section of manual page again to see the subset of allowed keywords):

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 94: Directive 'PrintMotd' is not allowed within a Match block
```

The solution should be as simple as moving your `Match` block to the true end of the file.